# 3 related problems - gap in content wrapper/border, image height reduced and positioning of content div

Tags: image, html, positioning, gaps-in-visuals

The problems can be seen here:  http://www.skicoloradorentals.com/secondary.html

1) the gap below the contentBorderImg
2) contentBorderImg reduces to 69 pixel height instead of 87 (18 px diff = same as gap)
3) the content div doesn't sit over the contentBorderImg even though I assigned a high z-index to it

## contentBorder - this is the wrapper/border for the content area with a 1-px border

## contentBorderImg - this is the rounded corner image which is displayed over the top part of the wrapper

.content - actual content div that I want to reside over the contentBorderImg

I was able to make the same concept work in the left column.  I tried duplicating that code to no avail.  I appreciate your help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving contentBorderImg's

```
Z-index = -1;
```

and then for #contentBorder use

```
border-radius:9px 9px 0px 0px;
```

I have used border-radius to mold the border as per the rounded corner image.